# Parsing quoted strings in C

Tags: c, parsing, unicode, compiler-construction

Is there native support for a data type for storing Unicode strings in C. I'm writing a toy compiler and would like to parse Unicode strings.

Comment: Are we to assume you mean the literal escape-sequences?

Comment: Unicode is supported to some degree with "Wide chars". Note that "unicode" means different things in different contexts. For example Microsoft means [in most places] a restricted set of characters that are 16-bits wide, with no encoding for characters outside of the first 16-bits of Unicode. Unicode itself is a 32-bit encoding, but there is 8- and 16-bit variants that allow encoding the full 32-bit range using multiple tokens as one character, the UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Unicode is actually a 21-bit encoding, not 32-bit.  In fact, the range is U+0000 to U+10FFFF, so it isn't even the full 21-bits (which would go to 0x1FFFFF).  This range means that UTF-8 never needs to go beyond 4 bytes, and UTF-16 can encode the values with one high surrogate 16-bit value (U+D800..U+DBFF) and one low surrogate 16-bit value (U+DC00..U+DFFF).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, [Unicode](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html) is a 31 bit encoding, and UTF-8 uses up to 6 bytes.

Comment: @vonbrand: No, it is not.  See: http://www.unicode.org/faq/blocks_ranges.html where it says '_Q: I understand that all Unicode characters are 16 bits [..]. Is that correct?_' and

'_A: Absolutely not! Unicode characters may be encoded at any code point from U+0000 to U+10FFFF. The size of the code unit used for expressing those code points may be 8 bits (for UTF-8), 16 bits (for UTF-16), or 32 bits (for UTF-32) [See UTF & BOM]. [...]_'  U+10FFFF requires 21 bits, not 31 bits.

Comment: See also Chapter 2 of the Unicode standard (p22 in the 6.2.0 version): _In the Unicode Standard, the codespace consists of the integers from 0 to 10FFFF/16, comprising
1,114,112 code points available for assigning the repertoire of abstract characters._

Comment: @MatsPetersson I believe that by "in most places" you mean "not in this millenium".

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @Griwes What do you mean? You are staring at it.

Comment: Questions tend to end with `?`, like in your last comment. You can do `echo "Is there native support for a data type for storing Unicode strings in C. I'm writing a toy compiler and would like to parse Unicode strings." | grep ?` and you will see for yourself there is no question in this - akhem - question.

Comment: You're writing a C compiler.  There isn't going to be anything in it that you don't put in there.  If you want unicode support, implement it or use somebody else's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there native support for a data type for storing Unicode strings in C.

Yes. Since Unicode strings can be *stored* as sequences of bytes using an encoding scheme, one can use arrays of `char` for this purpose.

Note that supporting storage says nothing about the ability to interpret or manipulate the data.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a spec for implementers?